# Generate static files from Angular 2 seed project

Tags: angular, angular2-seed

I am developing an application using [Angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed). I am trying to make a static demo but some resources are not found.

The `npm run build.dev` creates the following files in the project directory:

`project
|-- dev
    |-- app
        |-- app files...
    |-- css
        |-- main.css
        |-- other css files...
    |-- index.html
    |-- tsconfig.json`

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Dashboard</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css?1474900046924">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/dev/css/main.css?1474900046926">
<!-- More css... -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

```
<sd-app>Loading...</sd-app>

<script>
// Fixes undefined module function in SystemJS bundle
function module() {}
</script>

<script src="/app/system-config.js"></script>

<!-- libs:js -->
<script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?1474900046920"></script>
<!-- More libs... -->
<!-- endinject -->

<script>
System.import('app/main')
  .catch(function (e) {
    console.error(e,
      'Report this error at https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues');
  });
</script>
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css?1474900046924
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///dist/dev/css/main.css?1474900046926
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///app/system-config.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

So, the resources not found because the browser tries to find them in the root directory.

However, if I change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/dev/css/main.css?1474900046926">
```

To this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css?1474900046926">
```

It only works with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/<absolute-path>/dist/dev/css/main.css?1474900046926">
```

But this is really annoying and `System` is not found yet.

Any idea of how to do it?

## Update

I am already injecting css assets and js libraries using `project.config.ts` file:

```
// Add `NPM` third-party libraries to be injected/bundled.
this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = [
  ...this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES,
  { src: 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', inject: true},
  // More css and js files
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put direct links to your CSS like that. Instead use project.config file to inject your CSS in your index.html. Look for this file under "tools/config" folder.

See: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/wiki/Add-external-scripts-and-styles

Comment: Yes, I was using `project.config.ts` file to inject CSS and JS files.

Comment: @marc_aragones, there seems to be some problem the way bootstrap package is configured. How come you have "bootstrap/dist/dev" folder? My folder is like "bootstrap/dist/css". What is the version of bootstrap you have in your package.json?

Comment: `"bootstrap": "^3.3.7"`

Answer (score 0):

You should not inject css files that are in your project directly in your index.html. Main.css is injected by the seed and bootstrap css should be added via project.config.ts. See : https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/wiki/Add-external-scripts-and-styles